# fast concatenation of large amount of homogeneous dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have about 7000 homogeneous DataFrames (same columns but different sizes) and want to concat them into one big DataFrame for further analysis.

If I generate all of them and store into a `list` the memory would explode, so I cannot use `pandas.concat([...all my tables...])`, but choose to do the following:

```
bit_table = None
for table in readTables():
    big_table = pandas.concat([big_table, table], ignore_index=True)
```

I am wondering about the efficiency of the `for loop` way compared with the `pandas.concat([...all tables...])` way. Are they of the same speed?

Since the tables are homogeneous and the indexes do not matter, are there any tricks that can accelerate the concatenating?

Comment: If it's all homogeneous then using numpy's `hstack` or `vstack` might be a good option.  I'm not sure if that will help that much though.

Comment: It looks like you just want to append all tables together (vertically). If that's the case, you might want to consider `append` in a `pd.HDFStore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to use `pd.HDFStore` to append many tables together.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import time

# your tables
# =========================================
columns = ['col{}'.format(i) for i in range(100)]
data = np.random.randn(100000).reshape(1000, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# many tables, generator
def get_generator(df, n=1000):
    for x in range(n):
        yield df

table_reader = get_generator(df, n=1000)


# processing
# =========================================
# create a hdf5 storage, compression level 5, (1-9, 9 is extreme)
h5_file = pd.HDFStore('/home/Jian/Downloads/my_hdf5_file.h5', complevel=5, complib='blosc')

Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: /home/Jian/Downloads/my_hdf5_file.h5
Empty


t0 = time()

# loop over your df
counter = 1
for frame in table_reader:
    print('Appending Table {}'.format(counter))
    h5_file.append('big_table', frame, complevel=5, complib='blosc')
    counter += 1

t1 = time()

# Appending Table 1
# Appending Table 2
# ...
# Appending Table 999
# Appending Table 1000


print(t1-t0)

Out[3]: 41.6630880833

# check our hdf5_file
h5_file

Out[7]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: /home/Jian/Downloads/my_hdf5_file.h5
/big_table            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->1000000,ncols->100,indexers->[index])

# close hdf5
h5_file.close()

# very fast to retrieve your data in any future IPython session

h5_file = pd.HDFStore('/home/Jian/Downloads/my_hdf5_file.h5')

%time my_big_table = h5_file['big_table']

CPU times: user 217 ms, sys: 1.11 s, total: 1.33 s
Wall time: 1.89 s
```

Comment: Many thanks to @Jianxun Li. Your idea reminds me of real big data like mapreduce that uses hard drive for storage. Very intersting!